# Maintain state of page after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm tryiing to save the state of a page i load into a div onclick function. When i click on the link the page is loaded into the div correctly but when i refresh the page i lose the content and will have to click again to load

```
<script language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#foo').click(function () {
        $('#bar').load('news.asp');

        localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':visible'));
    });
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true') {
        $('#bar').show()
    }
});

</script>
```

html

```
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the content in `localStorage`, not the result of `.is(':visible')`.

You also need to append the content to `#bar` when the page refreshes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $bar = $('#bar');
    $('#foo').click(function () {
        $bar.load('news.asp');
        localStorage.setItem('display', $bar.html());
    });

    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block !== null) {
        $bar.html(block).show()
    }
});
```

Comment: it loads the page alright but when i refresh i still have to click again

Comment: Are you able to provide a live demonstration?

Comment: sorry for the first comment that was not what i was suppose to write, the real problem is i have to click twice before the page is loaded into the localstorage and then when i refresh it loads up. But when i want it to do it to first onclick the page should be loaded into the div and then when i refresh i still maintain the content. i would have love to give a live demonstration but don't know how